# What's source/binary overrides in Debian packaging?

Tags: package-management, packaging

When I `dput -f myhost foobar_x.x.x.changes`, it successful uploaded the package, but produced the following warnings:

```
foobar has no source override entry
foobar has no binary override entry either
```

How can I specify the source/binary overrides, and/or just suppress the warnings?

I'm using `mini-dinstall` as the backend aptitude repository manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have forgotten how to handle `dput` correctly and know nothing about `mini-dinstall`.

The overrides file may contain overides for the section and priority fields of Debian packages. A package has these two embedded, but a repository might decide to give different values. For instance, when I upload to Debian, it is not my decision alone whether a package is *required* or not.

Generally, the warning is harmless and can be ignored. The override file is an option for `dpkg-scanpackages` (which I suppose is used behind the scenes by `mini-dinstall` as well). The file contains lines of the form

```
package-name priority section
```

Comment: Because I have managed too many packages, and there are too many overrides warnings each time doing `dput`. So how can I specify those overrides so as to filter the warnings away?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the override warning messages are coming from the `apt-ftparchive` command. This is invoked by `mini-dinstall` to create the `Package` and `Source` files.

I managed to make `apt-ftparchive` read a source override file by setting an `apt.conf` setting. Unfortunately this is global for all users of `apt-ftparchive` on that machine but I only use it as part of `mini-dinstall` so it works for me.

1. Create a source override file with appropriate entries. In this example I used `/etc/apt/dinstall-src-override` but it could be anywhere that is readable by `mini-dinstall`.

   ```
   opencv  optional        graphics
   digikam optional        graphics        an.other@example.com
   ```

   The contents of this file are as per standard Debian guidelines. To save searching the following are useful: [Debian FTP Master's override file](https://wiki.debian.org/FtpMaster/Override); [Debian Policy allowable "Sections"](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections); and [Debian Policy allowable package "Priorities"](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-priorities).
2. Configure that apt-ftparchive uses the override file. Create a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90mini-dinstall-override` file with contents

   ```
   APT::FTPArchive::SourceOverride "/etc/apt/dinstall-src-override";
   ```

With this setup I no-longer get the override entry warnings. Of course the overrides used should be sensible because they are used in the archive!

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tidbit since I'm in the same boat: the file format is documented in [deb-override](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/deb-override.5.html). I haven't found where mini-dinstall (or apt-ftparchive; dpkg-scansources and dpkg-scanpackages weren't involved here) autoloads these from.

Comment: I have the issue when I run `apt-ftparchive sources > Sources`. As Richm mentioned, it gets called by `mini-dinstall`.